How can I create a test automation using selenium java and UTAM?
I am working on automating website navigation using Selenium WebDriver in Java. My goal is to create a test automation script that can navigate to any website and interact with elements based on a JSON configuration file using java.
I am trying to follow the .json file in this UTAM tutorial, but I want to write the test automation in Java not really java script. This website uses JavaScript for it's test automation but I want to try to code this is Java.
Here is the website I am trying to look at and use: https://utam.dev/tutorial/introduction
So I tried to click on the image tab on the main google page:https://www.google.com/
so my .json format to look like this but I am not sure what selector I am supposed to use and how to pick the proper element when I inspect the HTML web element.
{
    "root": true,
    "selector": {
      "css": "div"
    },
    "shadow": {
    "elements": [
      {
        "name": "clickImage",
        "type": "clickable",
        "selector": {
          "css": "div"
        }
        
        }
    ]
  }
 }


Here is the test automation that was written in java:
package com.utam;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Sofft {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\basavarajn\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Open the website
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

           
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\UTAM\\utam-sample\\src\\test\\utam\\test.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;

            String rootSelector = (String) jsonObject.get("selector");
            
        JSONArray elementsArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("elements");
        JSONObject firstElement = (JSONObject) elementsArray.get(0);
        String buttonSelector = (String) firstElement.get("selector");


        WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(buttonSelector));
        searchButton.click();

        
    }
} 

I am not sure where my error could be, but I assume it could be the .json file. I have added all the dependencies(this is in Maven). Please help!!

Based on the JSON provided:
"selector": {
  "css": "div"
}

selector is an Object that contains an object called css.
In your Java Code, when you call:
String buttonSelector = (String) firstElement.get("selector");

The get("selector") will probably return something like: { "css": "div" }.
You'd probably want to get the css object.
String buttonSelector = (String) firstElement.get("selector").get("css");

